# How to you make a constraint saying that all quantities of product A and B must be above 0 in a linear programming model that minimizes cost?

Tags: r, optimization, linear-programming

I'm using the lpSolve package for linear programming. I have product A, B and C, its associate cost and constraints concerning nutrition.

When I run this it says that Product A and B should be 0. How do I make a constraint to make sure Product A,B and C have solution values above 0?

```
cost<-c(50,30,20)
wf<-c(23,20,19)
vit<-c(20,10,30)

  #decision variation (aka min cost)
  objective.in = cost
  wf<-c(23,20,19)
  vit<-c(20,10,30)

#constraint matrix
const.mat<-matrix(c(vit),nrow=1, byrow=TRUE)

#define constraints
nutrient_contraint=970

#add in constraint
const.rhs =c(nutrient_contraint)

#constraint direction
const.dir=c(">=")

#find optimum
optimum = lp(direction="min", objective.in,const.mat,const.dir,const.rhs)

#optimum value for amount of A,B,C
optimum$solution

#check value of objective function at optimal point
optimum$objval
```

Comment: Please provide a specific problem including all code and inputs.

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but you can always specify the bounds A>=1 and B>=1 (or some other minimum value).

Comment: Suggest adding your objective and constraints for better clarity. 
Without any more details, all I can think of is to add inequality constraints for A, B and C to be greater than 0